# How can I change the color of C# preprocessor directive attribute in VS17?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I know how to change the color of C++ preprocessor directive attributes in Tools->Options...->Fonts and Colors->C++ Macros, but how can I change it for C#?

Here's how the same code shows up for C++ and C#:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For C# it's Tools->Options->Environment->Font and Colors->Preprocessor Keyword